# What would be the worst case run time of my two algorithms

Tags: python, runtime, big-o

I'm having a really hard time understanding how to calculate worst case run times and run times in general. Since there is a while loop, would the run time have to be n+1 because the while loop must run 1 additional time to check is the case is still valid?I've also been searching online for a good explanation/ practice on how to calculate these run times but I can't seem to find anything good. A link to something like this would be very much appreciated.

```
def reverse1(lst):
    rev_lst = []
    i = 0
    while(i < len(lst)):
       rev_lst.insert(0, lst[i])
       i += 1
    return rev_lst

def reverse2(lst):
    rev_lst = []
    i = len(lst) - 1
    while (i >= 0):
       rev_lst.append(lst[i])
       i -= 1
    return rev_lst
```

Comment: Are you asking how to time the actual execution of these?

Comment: Actually it does not make a significant difference, whether your algorithm performs with O(n) or (n+1). To build the reverse of a string with n characters, you need n steps at least. If you need O(n^2), your algorithm is inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Constant factors or added values don't matter for big-O run times, so you're over-complicating this. The run time is `O(n)` (linear) for `reverse2`, and `O(n**2)` (quadratic) for `reverse1` (because `list.insert(0, x)` is itself a `O(n)` operation, performed `O(n)` times).

Big-O runtime calculations are about how the algorithm behaves as the input size increases towards infinity, and the smaller factors don't matter here; `O(n + 1)` is the same as `O(n)` (as is `O(5n)` for that matter; as `n` increases, the constant multiplier of `5` is irrelevant to the *change* in runtime), `O(n**2 + n)` is still just `O(n**2)`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Since the number of iterations is fixed for any given size of the input list for both functions, the "worst" time complexity would be the same as the "best" and the average here.

In `reverse1`, the operation of inserting an item into a list at index 0 costs *O(n)* because it has to copy all the items to their following positions, and coupled with the `while` loop that iterates for the number of times of the size of the input list, the time complexity of `reverse1` would be *O(n^2)*.

There's no such an issue in `reverse2`, however, since the `append` method costs just *O(1)* to execute, so its overall time complexity is *O(n)*.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to give you a mathematical explanation of why extra iterations and operations with constant time doesn't matter.

This is O(n) since the definition of Big-Oh is that for f(n) ∈ O(g(n)) there exists some *constant* k such that f(n) < kg(n).

Consider an algorithm with runtime represented as f(n) = 10000n + 15000000. A way you could simplify this is by factoring out the n: f(n) = n(10000 + 15000000/n). For the worst case runtime, you only care about the performance of the algorithm for super large values of n. Because in this simplification you're dividing by n, in the second part, as n gets really big, the coefficient of n will approach 10000, since 15000000/n approaches 0 if n is enormous. Therefore, for n > N (this means for a large enough value of n) there must exist a constant k such that f(n) < kn, for example k = 10001. Therefore, f(n) ∈ O(n), it has linear runtime efficiency.

With that being said, this means you don't need to worry about constant differences in your runtime, even if you loop n+1 times. The only part that matter (for polynomial time) is the highest degree of n in your code. Your reverse algorithms are O(n) runtime, and even if you iterated n + 1000 times, it would still be O(n) runtime.